# convertir mysql query a django

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-views

Chicos! 
Tengo este query que quiero usar en Django y no encuentro la forma de hacerlo espero me puedan ayudar:

```
SELECT herramienta_id, SUM(cantidad) FROM inventario_transaccion 
WHERE carrito_id=1 
GROUP BY herramienta_id
```

Lo que quiero hacer es obtener una lista de herramientas unicas y hacer la sumatoria de cantidade. Ejemplo

```
herramienta   cantidad
+-----------+----------+
| martillo  |    2     |
| clavos    |    1     |
| martillo  |    1     |
+-----------+----------+
```

me de como resultado

```
herramienta   cantidad
+-----------+----------+
| martillo  |    3     |
| clavos    |    1     |
+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: Si nos muestras como están construido tus modelos, quizás podríamos ayudarte un poco

Comment: @GermanAlzate. Gracias! Ayer después de horas de frustración y sufrimiento encontré la forma de hacer el query que necesitaba:
`Transaccion.objects.values('herramienta__description').annotate(Sum('cantidad')).filter(activo=True, carrito_id=pk)`, pero agradesco mucho tu disposición. Saludos